# 'module' object has no attribute 'feature_column'

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I ran the official tutorial from Google ([link here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/getting-started-training-prediction)). It ran fine locally but I got stuck on the part where I need to train the network on the Google Cloud Platform. I ran the following code on my terminal:

```
JOB_NAME=census_single_1
OUTPUT_PATH=gs://$BUCKET_NAME/$JOB_NAME
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
--job-dir $OUTPUT_PATH \
--runtime-version 1.0 \
--module-name trainer.task \
--package-path trainer/ \
--region $REGION \
-- \
--train-files $TRAIN_DATA \
--eval-files $EVAL_DATA \
--train-steps 1000 \
--verbosity DEBUG
```

And I got the following error message:

> "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File
>   \"/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 162, in _run_module_as_main\n
>   \"**main**\", fname, loader, pkg_name)\n  File
>   \"/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 72, in _run_code\n    exec code
>   in run_globals\n  File
>   \"/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py\", line 4,
>   in \n    import model\n  File
>   \"/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/model.py\", line
>   40, in \n
>   tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(\nAttributeError:
>   'module' object has no attribute 'feature_column'\n"

// **UPDATE**

Never mind. I figured it out. It turns out the `--runtime-version` argument controls the Cloud ML Runtime Version ([link](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/concepts/runtime-version-list)). In the tutorial it was specified as 1.0, and that corresponds to Tensorflow v 1.0.1, which does not have `tf.feature_column.*` because it was just introduced in Tensorflow v 1.2.0 on June 16, 2017

// **UPDATE 2**

The Google tutorial has been updated to use `--runtime-version 1.2` instead of `--runtime-version 1.0` as of today, Jun 29, 2017. I don't know if they saw my post but this was changed between Jun 28 and Jun 29. Future users on that tutorial shouldn't experience the same issue I had.

Comment: same pb here. Version should be added to TensorFlow

Comment: if you are happy with my answer feel free to mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 4):

This could also happen from updating Google Cloud SDK, in which case `pip install --upgrade tensorflow` should do the job.

Comment: or `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow` for python3.x

Comment: This does not give any result

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem with an outdated version of tensorflow. Updating it to the latest build helped.

Comment: This does not give any result